# Importing python script to zabbix?

Tags: python, grafana, zabbix

So ive made a easy python script to monitor DB sizes in my postgres but now id like to form graphs about the results to be monitored. However i cannot find a single way to get this script into the WEB GUI to be used in zabbix/grafana. We use zabbix and grafana on top of that simply because grafana looks way better.

```
# pip install psycopg2-binary
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "postgres", password = "password", host = "server", port = 
"5432", database = "postgres")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false")
records = cursor.fetchall()

for record in records:
    cursor.execute("SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size('{}'))".format(record[0]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print("DB:{} Size:{}".format(record[0], row[0]))
```

Ive been googleing around the entire morning but i cant find any information about this. Ive found that it should be added to /zabbix/externalscripts folder but i did so and now i have no clue how to access it and add to a graph.

Comment: Okay so ive now made a crontab job to write the results in a txt file and ive found you can use "userparameter" to read the file into zabbix which is located in "/tmp/file.txt" and ive added a parameter in zabbix_agent.conf but reading the manual i cannot udnerstand how you supposed to read the file still. https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/userparameters

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with multiple databases and for each of them you want the size: you need to implement a [Low Level Discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery) for your target host.

The discovery rule should produce a json like:

```
{
    "data":  [
                 {
                     "{#DBNAME}":  "Database 1",
                     "{#SOMEOTHERPROPERTY}":  "XXX"
                 },
                 {
                     "{#DBNAME}":  "Database 2",
                     "{#SOMEOTHERPROPERTY}":  "YYY"
                 }
             ] }
```

Then you have to create an item prototype which uses {#DBNAME} as a reference, to query the db size.

You can create both the LLD and the item prototype using the [ODBC support](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/odbc_checks).

For instance, your [OBDC discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery/sql_queries) should be:

```
Key = db.odbc.discovery[get_databases,{HOST.NAME}]
Params = SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false
```

And your item prototype:

```
Key = db.odbc.select[Used size on {#datname},{HOST.NAME}]
Params = SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size('{#datname}'))
```

After this setup, you will have an item for each database (and new databases will be discovered dynamically): you can plot them with latest data, with Grafana or by defining Graph Prototypes.